# Spark 2.x using HiveThriftServer2 with sqlContext

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, spark-thriftserver

My requirement is to enable ODBC/JDBC access to a SparkSQL *temporary* table, for which there was a DataFrame in Spark (mix of JSON-based and streaming).

I made it working in Spark 1.6, and then recently upgraded to Spark to 2.1.1. I adjusted my code as the second answering person in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732245/cant-access-spark-2-0-temporary-table-from-beeline/39999981#39999981). I noticed the deprecation warning on this clause, however:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(spark.sparkContext)
```

So I checked [javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html) on sqlContext, and it says "Deprecated. Use SparkSession.builder instead. Since 2.0.0." But then, accordingly to even the latest [HiveThriftserver2.scala code in git](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/HiveThriftServer2.scala), the method startWithContext requires the parameter of type sqlContext.

So, could anyone in the know shed some light on this:

1. Have I picked the right way to solve the problem, in the first place? I'd love not to start HiveThriftServer2 from within my Spark code, but then /sbin/start-thriftserver.sh doesn't provide me an option to start a thriftserver instance with *my* class. Or, does it, and I'm just missing it?
2. Is there another way to start HiveThriftServer2 from the Spark code, using SparkSession?

Comment: The Thrift server start script just opens and runs a Java/Scala class as far as I know

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, and that class is not the class I want to supply (if I understand the script right), but HiveThriftServer2 class; I just wanted to double-check that my understanding was correct.

Comment: Right here is the line you want if you want to programmatically create that object. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/HiveThriftServer2.scala#L91

Comment: SparkSession + SQLContext come out of this line. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive-thriftserver/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/thriftserver/SparkSQLEnv.scala#L50

Comment: @cricket_007 oh thank you very much, I should have checked doc for sparkSession more closely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create an SQLContext any more. Juste take it from spark session.

```
val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("Your application name")
        .getOrCreate()

val sqlContext: SQLContext = spark.sqlContext
HiveThriftServer2.startWithContext(sqlContext)
```